# SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas with iloc and iterrow

Tags: python

```
def set_id(para_in_datax):
    w = data[para_in_datax].copy()
    for idx,i in w.iterrows():
        ida = find_id(para_in_datax, i)

        if ida == False:
            continue
        else:
            datax.loc[idx,para_in_datax[0]] = ida
```

How come I can't avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning?
What did i do wrong?
Or is it a false positive?

Could you please help me to fix that ?

Comment: This might help- https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)